# Como criar várias variáveis do mesmo tipo sem repetir condições?

Tags: java, funções, variáveis, if, condição

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {



Categoria c1 = new Categoria();
    c1.categoria = "-Reprodução";
    c1.nome = "Ahmed Shafik";
    c1.ano = "2016";
    c1.justificativa = "por pesquisar os efeitos do uso de calças de poliéster, algodão e lã na vida sexual dos ratos e depois repetir a experiência em homens.";

Categoria c2 = new Categoria();
    c2.categoria = "-Economia";
    c2.nome = "Mark Avis, Sarah Forbes e Shelagh Ferguson";
    c2.ano = "2016";
    c2.justificativa = "por descobrirem as personalidades das rochas, de uma perspectiva de vendas e marketing.";

Categoria c3= new Categoria();
    c3.categoria = "-Física";
    c3.nome = "Gábor Horváth, Miklós Blahó, György Kriska, Ramón Hegedüs, Balázs Gerics, Róbert Farkas, Susanne Åkesson, Péter Malik e Hansruedi Wildermuth";
    c3.ano = "2016";
    c3.justificativa = "por descobrirem por que cavalos de pelos brancos são menos atacados por moscas, e por descobrirem por que libélulas são atraídas por lápides pretas.";

Categoria c4= new Categoria();
    c4.categoria = "-Química";
    c4.nome = "Volkswagen";
    c4.ano = "2016";
    c4.justificativa = "por resolver o problema das emissões excessivas de gases poluentes nos seus automóveis de forma automática, produzindo menos emissões sempre que estão sendo testados.";

Categoria c5= new Categoria();
    c5.categoria = "-Medicina";
    c5.nome = "Christoph Helmchen, Carina Palzer, Thomas Münte, Silke Anders e Andreas Sprenger";
    c5.ano = "2016";
    c5.justificativa = "por descobrirem que quando se tem uma coceira no lado esquerdo do corpo, esta pode ser aliviada olhando para um espelho e coçando o lado direito do corpo e vice-versa.";

Categoria c6= new Categoria();
    c6.categoria = "-Psicologia";
    c6.nome = "Evelyne Debey, Maarten De Schryver, Gordon Logan, Kristina Suchotzki e Bruno Verschuere";
    c6.ano = "2016";
    c6.justificativa = "por perguntar a mil mentirosos com que frequência eles mentem, e qual a probabilidade de que eles tenham sido sinceros nas respostas.";

Categoria c7= new Categoria();
    c7.categoria = "-Paz";
    c7.nome = "Gordon Pennycook, James Allan Cheyne, Nathaniel Barr, Derek Koehler e Jonathan Fugelsang";
    c7.ano = "2016";
    c7.justificativa = "por seu estudo acadêmico ''Sobre a Compreensão e Detecção de Idiotices Pseudo-Profundas''.";

Categoria c8= new Categoria();
    c8.categoria = "-Biologia";
    c8.nome = "Charles Foster e Thomas Thwaites";
    c8.ano = "2016";
    c8.justificativa = "Charles, por viver na natureza, em momentos diferentes, como um texugo, uma lontra, um veado, uma raposa e um pássaro; Thomas por projetar próteses para seus membros, que lhe permitiram deslocar-se pelas montanhas na companhia de cabras.";

Categoria c9= new Categoria();
    c9.categoria = "-Literatura";
    c9.nome = "Fredrik Sjöberg";
    c9.ano = "2016";
    c9.justificativa = "por sua obra autobiográfica em três volumes, relatando o prazer de colecionar moscas mortas, e moscas que ainda não haviam morrido.";

Categoria c10= new Categoria();
    c10.categoria = "-Percepção";
    c10.nome = "Atsuki Higashiyama e Kohei Adachi";
    c10.ano = "2016";
    c10.justificativa = "por investigar o quanto os objetos parecem diferentes, quando se curva para visualizá-los por entre as pernas.";

Categoria c11= new Categoria();
    c11.categoria = "-Química";
    c11.nome = "Callum Ormonde e Colin Raston";
    c11.ano = "2015";
    c11.justificativa = "por inventarem uma receita química que faz ''descozinhar'' parcialmente um ovo.";

Categoria c12= new Categoria();
    c12.categoria = "-Física";
    c12.nome = "Patricia Yang, David Hu, Jonathan Pham e Jerome Choo";
    c12.ano = "2015";
    c12.justificativa = "por testarem o princípio biológico de que quase todos os mamíferos esvaziam suas bexigas em cerca de 21 segundos (mais ou menos 13 segundos).";

Categoria c13= new Categoria();
    c13.categoria = "-Literatura";
    c13.nome = "Mark Dingemanse, Francisco Torreira e Nick J. Enfield";
    c13.ano = "2015";
    c13.justificativa = "por descobrirem que a palavra ''huh?'' (ou seu equivalente) parece existir em cada linguagem humana - e por não terem certeza do porque.";

Categoria c14= new Categoria();
    c14.categoria = "-Gestão";
    c14.nome = "Gennaro Bernile, Vineet Bhagwat e P. Raghavendra Rau";
    c14.ano = "2015";
    c14.justificativa = "por descobrirem que muitos líderes de negócios desenvolveram na infância uma predileção por assumir riscos, quando experimentaram desastres naturais como terremotos, erupções vulcânicas, tsunamis e incêndios florestais que, para eles, não tiveram qualquer consequência pessoal tão terrível.";

Categoria c15= new Categoria();
    c15.categoria = "-Economia";
    c15.nome = "Polícia Metropolitana de Bangkok, Tailândia";
    c15.ano = "2015";
    c15.justificativa = "por oferecer aos policiais um pagamento extra em dinheiro se estes se recusarem a aceitar subornos.";

Categoria c16= new Categoria();
    c16.categoria = "-Medicina";
    c16.nome = "Hajime Kimata, Jaroslava Durdiaková, Peter Celec, Natália Kamodyová, Tatiana Sedláčková, Gabriela Repiská, Barbara Sviežená e Gabriel Minárik";
    c16.ano = "2015";
    c16.justificativa = "por seus experimentos ao estudar os benefícios ou consequências biomédicas do beijo intenso e outras atividades interpessoais íntimas.";

Categoria c17= new Categoria();
    c17.categoria = "-Matemática";
    c17.nome = "Elisabeth Oberzaucher e Karl Grammer";
    c17.ano = "2015";
    c17.justificativa = "por tentarem usar técnicas matemáticas para determinar se e como Mulai Ismail, o Sanguinário, Imperador de Marrocos conseguiu, durante os anos de 1697 a 1727, ser pai de 888 filhos.";

Categoria c18= new Categoria();
    c18.categoria = "-Biologia";
    c18.nome = "Bruno Grossi, Omar Larach, Mauricio Canals, Rodrigo A. Vásquez e José Iriarte-Díaz";
    c18.ano = "2015";
    c18.justificativa = "por observarem que, quando se prende um bastão de peso calculado à extremidade traseira de um frango, este passa a caminhar de maneira semelhante à que os dinossauros supostamente caminhavam.";

Categoria c19= new Categoria();
    c19.categoria = "-Fisiologia e Entomologia";
    c19.nome = "Justin Schmidt";
    c19.ano = "2015";
    c19.justificativa = "por criar meticulosamente o ''Índice Schmidt de Dor em Ferroadas'', que classifica a dor relativa que as pessoas sentem quando picadas por variados insetos, e Michael L. Smith, por cuidadosamente organizar abelhas para picá-lo repetidamente em 25 locais diferentes do seu corpo, para saber quais locais são os menos dolorosos (crânio, extremidade do dedo médio e parte superior do braço) e quais são os mais dolorosos (narina, lábio superior e pênis).";

Categoria c20= new Categoria();
    c20.categoria = "-Física";
    c20.nome = "Kiyoshi Mabuchi, Kensei Tanaka, Daichi Uchijima e Rina Sakai";
    c20.ano = "2014";
    c20.justificativa = "por medir a quantidade de atrito entre um sapato e uma casca de banana, e entre a casca de banana e o chão, quando uma pessoa pisa em uma casca de banana no chão.";

IgNobel i1= new IgNobel();
    i1.nome = "Guardador De Categorias:";

i1.categoria.add(c1);
i1.categoria.add(c2);
i1.categoria.add(c3);
i1.categoria.add(c4);
i1.categoria.add(c5);
i1.categoria.add(c6);
i1.categoria.add(c7);
i1.categoria.add(c8);
i1.categoria.add(c9);
i1.categoria.add(c10);
i1.categoria.add(c11);
i1.categoria.add(c12);
i1.categoria.add(c13);
i1.categoria.add(c14);
i1.categoria.add(c15);
i1.categoria.add(c16);
i1.categoria.add(c17);
i1.categoria.add(c18);
i1.categoria.add(c19);
i1.categoria.add(c20);

System.out.println(i1.nome);
    i1.listarTodasAsCategorias();
    System.out.println("");



    System.out.println("Digite a categoria e o ano (ex. fisica 2016), ou o nome do ganhador (ex. ahmed shafik): ");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String textoString = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(textoString);



        if(textoString.equals("reproduçao 2016") || textoString.equals("REPRODUÇAO 2016")){
            System.out.println(c1.categoria);
        c1.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("economia 2016") || textoString.equals("ECONOMIA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c2.categoria);
        c2.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("fisica 2016") || textoString.equals("FISICA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c3.categoria);
        c3.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("quimica 2016") || textoString.equals("QUIMICA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c4.categoria);
        c4.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("medicina 2016") || textoString.equals("MEDICINA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c5.categoria);
        c5.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("psicologia 2016") || textoString.equals("PSICOLOGIA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c6.categoria);
        c6.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("paz 2016") || textoString.equals("PAZ 2016")){
            System.out.println(c7.categoria);
        c7.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("biologia 2016") || textoString.equals("BIOLOGIA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c8.categoria);
        c8.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("literatura 2016") || textoString.equals("LITERATURA 2016")){
            System.out.println(c9.categoria);
        c9.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("percepçao 2016") || textoString.equals("PERCEPÇAO 2016")){
            System.out.println(c10.categoria);
        c10.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("quimica 2015") || textoString.equals("QUIMICA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c11.categoria);
        c11.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("fisica 2015") || textoString.equals("FISICA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c12.categoria);
        c12.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("literatura 2015") || textoString.equals("LITERATURA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c13.categoria);
        c13.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("gestao 2015") || textoString.equals("GESTAO 2015")){
            System.out.println(c14.categoria);
        c14.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("economia 2015") || textoString.equals("ECONOMIA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c15.categoria);
        c15.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("medicina 2015") || textoString.equals("MEDICINA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c16.categoria);
        c16.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("matematica 2015") || textoString.equals("MATEMATICA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c17.categoria);
        c17.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("biologia 2015") || textoString.equals("BIOLOGIA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c18.categoria);
        c18.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("fisiologia e entomologia 2015") || textoString.equals("FISIOLOGIA E ENTOMOLOGIA 2015")){
            System.out.println(c19.categoria);
        c19.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        if(textoString.equals("fisica 2014") || textoString.equals("FISICA 2014")){
            System.out.println(c20.categoria);
        c20.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");

        }

        //pesquisa pelo nome do ganhador//

        if(textoString.equals("ahmed shafik")){
            System.out.println(c1.categoria);
        c1.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("mark avis") || textoString.equals("sarah forbes") || textoString.equals("shelagh ferguson")){
            System.out.println(c2.categoria);
        c2.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("gabor horvath") || textoString.equals("miklos blaho") || textoString.equals("gyorgy kriska") || textoString.equals("ramon hegedus") || textoString.equals("balazs gerics") || textoString.equals("robert farkas") || textoString.equals("susanne akesson") || textoString.equals("peter malik") || textoString.equals("hansruedi wildermuth")){
            System.out.println(c3.categoria);
        c3.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("volkswagen")){
            System.out.println(c4.categoria);
        c4.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("christoph helmchen") || textoString.equals("carina palzer") || textoString.equals("thomas munte") || textoString.equals("silke anders") || textoString.equals("andreas sprenger")){
            System.out.println(c5.categoria);
        c5.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("evelyne debey") || textoString.equals("maarten de schryver") || textoString.equals("gordon logan") || textoString.equals("kristina suchotzki") || textoString.equals("bruno verschuere")){
            System.out.println(c6.categoria);
        c6.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("gordon pennycook") || textoString.equals("james allan cheyne") || textoString.equals("nathaniel barr") || textoString.equals("derek koehler") || textoString.equals("jonathan fugelsang")){
            System.out.println(c7.categoria);
        c7.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("charles foster") || textoString.equals("thomas thwaites")){
            System.out.println(c8.categoria);
        c8.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("fredrik sjoberg")){
            System.out.println(c9.categoria);
        c9.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("atsuki higashiyama") || textoString.equals("kohei adachi")){
            System.out.println(c10.categoria);
        c10.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("callum ormonde") || textoString.equals("colin raston")){
            System.out.println(c11.categoria);
        c11.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("patricia yang") || textoString.equals("david hu") || textoString.equals("jonathan pham") || textoString.equals("jerome choo")){
            System.out.println(c12.categoria);
        c12.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }

        if(textoString.equals("mark dingemanse") || textoString.equals("francisco torreira") || textoString.equals("nick j. enfield")){
            System.out.println(c13.categoria);
        c13.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
        }



        else{
          System.out.println("voce errou (-_-)");
        }









    //fim da pesquisa//

}
}



//classe categoria
class Categoria{
String categoria;
String nome;
String ano;
String justificativa; 
String busca;

  public Categoria(){

  }

  public void listarOsNomesEAnos(){
      String nomeAtual = nome;
      String anoAtual = ano;
      System.out.println(nomeAtual + ", " + anoAtual);
      }
}

class Pessoa{

  public Pessoa(){

  }
}

//classe ignobel
class IgNobel{
String nome;
 ArrayList<Categoria> categoria;

  public IgNobel(){
    this.categoria = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
  }
public void listarTodasAsCategorias(){
    for(int i =0;i<this.categoria.size();i++){
      String categAtual = this.categoria.get(i).categoria;
      System.out.println(categAtual);
    }
  }


   }
```

Nesse código Java, são criadas `20` variáveis para a classe `Categoria` de um prêmio `IgNobel`, a qual contém o nome da categoria, nome do/dos ganhadores, ano e justificativa. Logo após isso o usuário deve buscar o ganhador pelo nome e ano da categoria... O problema é que preciso de um jeito mais fácil de implementar uma nova categoria caso precise criar outra sem precisar criar outra condição de "caso seja escrito isso.. mostrar isso:

```
if(textoString.equals("biologia 2016") || textoString.equals("BIOLOGIA 2016")){
        System.out.println(c8.categoria);
    c8.listarOsNomesEAnos();
    System.out.println("");)
```

Sei que há um parÂmetro para simplificar, e preciso de um exemplo. Apenas como implementar mais categorias de forma simples. Agradeço.

Comment: Não me lembro de ver tanto código numa pergunta. Deveria ser resumido só ao problema em questão, que eu duvido que todo esse código seja relevante para o problema.

Comment: Você não precisa de tanto código, use métodos!

Comment: Por favor, tente refatorar esse código, deixando apenas o essencial para sua duvida, ler um código gigante desses é cansativo, e o problema as vezes está apenas num pedaço.

Answer (score 1):

Você já usa um `for` para listar todas as categorias, porque não utilizar outro para verificar se a categoria é a que pretende ?

Esse `for` ficaria assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < i1.categoria.size();++i){
    Categoria c = i1.categoria.get(i); //obter a categoria da lista

    //fazer teste de categoria e ano, ou nome
    if (textoString.equalsIgnoreCase(c.categoria+ " " + c.ano) ||
        textoString.equalsIgnoreCase(c.nome){

        //mostrar da forma que já estava a ser mostrado
        System.out.println(c.categoria);
        c.listarOsNomesEAnos();
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Também pode simplificar a construção das categorias criando um construtor de `Categoria` que receba os dados relevantes de cada categoria:

```
public Categoria(String categoria, String nome, int ano, String justificativa){
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.ano = ano;
    this.justificativa = justificativa;
}
```

Repare como coloquei `int ano`, pois o `ano` deve ser do tipo inteiro uma vez que guarda um numero. Isto simplifica porque a criação pode agora ficar assim:

```
//o antigo C1
i1.categoria.add(new Categoria("-Reprodução","Ahmed Shafik",2016,
"por pesquisar os efeitos do uso de calças de poliéster, algodão e lã na vida sexual dos ratos e depois repetir a experiência em homens.");

//o antigo C2
i1.categoria.add(new Categoria("-Economia","Mark Avis, Sarah Forbes e Shelagh Ferguson",2016,
"por descobrirem as personalidades das rochas, de uma perspectiva de vendas e marketing.");

//etc...
```

Para a informação que tem já sugiro usar nem que seja um ficheiro para guardar lá toda a informação e carregar as perguntas do ficheiro, que deixa o código mais limpo, e as categorias fáceis de manter e até de serem adicionadas por terceiros.

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi falado, tem muito código ai que não é necessário. Grande parte disso se deve ao mal uso da programação orientada a objetos. Alterei algumas coisas para tornar mais claro seu programa:

```
// Se categoria é um atributo não faz muito sentido ser o nome da classe
public class PremioNobel {

    // Por questões de segurança é importante que não haja
    // acesso direto aos atributos da classe. Isso se chama encapsulamento
    private String categoria;
    private String nome;
    private String ano;
    private String justificativa; 

    public PremioNobel (String categoria, String nome, String ano, String justificativa) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.justificativa = justificativa;
    }

    // Como os atributos agora são privados eles devem ter Getters e Setters
    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    public void setAno(String ano) {
       this.ano = ano;
    }

    public String getJustificativa() {
        return justificativa;
    }

    public void setJustificativa(String justificativa) {
        this.justificativa = justificativa;
    }    
}
```

Agora a classe principal, usando as streams do Java8:

Para criar um novo objeto PremioNobel usando o construtor fica assim (Ou você pode usar um construtor vazio e adicionar os dados através dos métodos set:

```
// Criando categoria com contrutores
PremioNobel p1 = new PremioNobel("-Reprodução", "Ahmed Shafik", "2016", "por pesquisar os efeitos do uso de calças de poliéster, algodão e lã na vida sexual dos ratos e depois repetir a experiência em homens.");
PremioNobel p2 = new PremioNobel("-Economia", "Mark Avis, Sarah Forbes e Shelagh Ferguson", "2016", "por descobrirem as personalidades das rochas, de uma perspectiva de vendas e marketing.");
```

Para adicionar todos os objetos PremioNobel de uma vez você pode fazer dessa forma (Não é necessário uma classe igNobel):

```
// Criando uma lista de prêmios       
List<PremioNobel> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(p1,p2, ...));
```

Ter métodos na sua classe facilita a navegação, veja como listar todas as categorias:

```
// Listar todas as categorias usando Streams
System.out.println("Todas as categorias: ");
lista.stream().forEach(premio -> System.out.println(premio.getCategoria()));

// Listar todas as categorias usando ForEach
for(PremioNobel p: lista){
    System.out.println(p.getCategoria()));
}
```

O código acima diz que para cada `PremioNobel` em `lista` imprima a categoria do mesmo.

**Para fazer uma busca por autor** temos duas maneiras:

```
List<PremioNobel> premios = lista.stream()
                .filter(autor -> autor.getNome().equals("Ahmed Shafik"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
// Crio uma stream() na lista
// .filter(condicao) : Filtra os Premios cujo o autor é igual a algo
// .collect retorna uma nova lista com os dados

for(PremioNobel p: lista){
    if(p.getNome().equals("Ahmed Shafik"){
        System.out.println("Imprime os dados do premio");
    }
}
```

Com isso você pode adaptar para fazer suas buscas. Para criar um novo objeto a qualquer momento basta instanciar (new PremioNobel(...)) e adicionar à sua lista usando o método `add()` veja o pseudocódigo abaixo:

```
while(condicao){
    PremioNobel p = new PremioNobel("categoria","ano","pesquisador","justificativa");
    lista.add(p);
    System.out.println("Deseja adicionar mais Premios?");
    // Algum código
}
```

Mas se forem muitos objetos (algo cansativo de fazer à mão) tente ler os dados de um arquivo e criar a lista de objetos PremioNobel a partir dele.